# How to make a nested function call within an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iife

```
const parkReport = () => {
     return {
       averageAge: () => {
          return console.log('Something');   
      }
     } 
    };
    const initialize = ( parkReport => {
      return parkReport.averageAge();
    })(parkReport);
```

In the IIFE `initialize` `parkReport.averageAge()` is showing an error of not a function. How do you call the nested `AverageAge()` from `initialize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `parkReport` function. Here you are passing `parkReport` as a `callback` to the `IIFE`. so you need to `call` it to expect something returned from it.

```js
const parkReport = () => {
  return {
    averageAge: () => {
      return console.log('Something');
    }
  }
};
const initialize = (parkReport => {
  return parkReport() // call it 
    .averageAge(); // and get the age
})(parkReport);
```

Comment: So would this have to be done for every consecutive call like `parkReport().averageAge().sumofAges()`?